# CMIS explorer webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, java-ee-6, ecm, cmis

[CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) is a recently approved standard for accessing [ECM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_content_management) repositories.

My idea is to create a repository explorer using CMIS, under the form of an open source Java/Java EE Web Application.

The main interest would probably be for [integrators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_integration), using it as a framework on which to quickly build repository access intranet/extranet applications.

Of course, if such an open source project already exists, I would rather contribute to it rather than start a competing effort.
So, does such an application/framework already exist? As open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [spring-cmis-application-browser](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/cmis/2010/06/14/spring-surf-and-opencmis-integration-part-2/), based on Spring Surf, usable as a desktop-like file explorer.
- [Struts2CmisExplorer](http://code.google.com/p/struts2cmisexplorer/), based on Struts2 and designed for integration into portals.
- [chemistry-opencmis-test-browser](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/chemistry/opencmis/trunk/chemistry-opencmis-test/chemistry-opencmis-test-browser/src/main/java/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/browser/BrowseServlet.java?view=markup), a minimalistic explorer webapp.

Comment: http://chemistry.apache.org/java/opencmis-browser.html does not say that it is intended for tests only.  Perhaps this changed at some point?

Answer (score 1):

DITA CMIS Explorer http://ditalabs.com

Comment: That company is dead, though maybe the word "DITA" still helps (or not).

Answer (score 1):

[**WeWebU OpenWorkdesk**](http://www.openworkdesk.org/) is an application suite (not just a CMIS browser!) for Enterprise Content Management (ECM) with an intuitive Web 2.0 front-end.
OpenWorkdesk applications are future-proof and protect your investments because the user interface and the application layer have been separated from the underlying ECM system. This separation allows you to continue using your applications without laborious modifications even after an upgrade or change of the ECM platform. OpenWorkdesk Community Edition is available for all CMIS-compliant ECM systems such as Alfresco ECM, IBM FileNet P8, Nuxeo and EMC Documentum. Therefore, it provides a very cost-efficient but nevertheless fully professional way of managing and retrieving documents.

Even users who do not have any ECM system experience can use state-of-the-art ECM functionalities with minimal training. Its user-friendly navigation with “Windows-like” shortcuts and right mouse button menus, and not at least its innovative Web 2.0 technologies assist users perfectly in dealing with their daily tasks.

(description above is taken from their website)